# Without a block explorer API, can I programmatically determine if an address has a contract deployed at it (eg using Web3 or call to a node)?

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, nodes

Given an address, from a web application I'm attempting to determine if there's a contract deployed at the address. There are some ways to do this with etherscan or other block explorer APIs, but I'm curious if this is possible directly from a node (perhaps from a node with instrumentation or debugging turned on?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

You can use the [`getCode` API](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#getcode). If that call returns `0x`, there is no contract at that address. If it returns anything other than `0x`, there is a contract at that address.

As an example:

```
web3.eth.getCode("0xd5677cf67b5aa051bb40496e68ad359eb97cfbf8")
.then(console.log);
> "0x600160008035811a818181146012578301005b601b6001356025565b8060005260206000f25b600060078202905091905056"
```